# I thought I did VS. I thought I have?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what is the right form to say between these two options:
I thought I did VS. I thought I have

In this example:

Person A: You know me, right?

Person B: I thought I did / I thought I have.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, which of these is correct:

> 1. I thought I did.

or

> 2. I thought I have.

The answer is #1.

At least one reason why the second answer is incorrect (and there may be more) is that "have" is the present perfect, which indicates "actions started in the past and continuing in the present". However in this dialog, the response is saying something truly about the past. Not the present perfect. In the present time, the speaker does not think they know.

Comment: You really should explain **why** #1 is correct. (We try to teach people how to fish here.)